# Reverse string without changing the position of special character using regex

Tags: java, string, special-characters, reverse

```
class der{
    public static void maxLength(String str) {
        String s = " ";
        s = str.replaceAll("[^a-z]+", " ");
        String rev = " ";
        char ch[] = s.toCharArray();
        for(int i =ch.length-1; i>=0 ; i--){
            rev = rev + ch[i];
        }
        System.out.println(rev);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String str = "a@utom!at$ion@";
        maxLength(str);
    }
}
```

I tried the above with regex function where i first tried to remove special character and then reverse the string. But is there any option to add special character back again to the reverse strings?
My o/p for the current code is this `noi ta motu a` so in blank space i want to put the special character again.

Comment: `maxLength()` seems like a terrible method name for your purposes. What's the expected outcome of `a@utom!at$ion@`?

Answer (score 0):

You may use this Java code:

```
String str = "a@utom!at$ion@";
// \W+ matches 1+ of any non-word characters
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\W+").matcher(str);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int start=0;
// loop through the matches of \W+
while (m.find()) {
   // append reverse of substring before current match
   // and then the match itself is appended in buffer
   sb
   .append(new StringBuilder(str.substring(start, m.start())).reverse())
   .append(m.group());
   start = m.end();
}
// append remaining part after last match in buffer
sb.append(new StringBuilder(str.substring(start)).reverse());
// print the results
System.out.println(sb);
```

**Output:**

```
a@motu!ta$noi@
```

Comment: @Alka: Did this work out?